# Closing context menu programmatically in fragment on different devices

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, contextmenu

I have a listview in my fragment. On longclick on an item in that listview I have a context menu. The last option in the menu is closing it (Close menu). This is how I did it:

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == 0) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case 1...
            case 2...
            case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE:
                getActivity().closeContextMenu();
            break;
        }
    }
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

I checked the app on my Samsung Galaxy S3 - it worked just fine. Now I sent the APK to a friend to check the app on his Nexus 3, and this option didn't work for him, the context menu didn't close.

What can be the reason for that and how can it be fixed?

Comment: what is `Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE` ?

Comment: @MehulJoisar It's an ID of that menu item. From my Constants class, and Context_Menu_Items class inside it: `public static final int CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE = 3;`

Comment: getActivity().closeContextMenu(); do this it will close the contextmenu programmatically

Answer (score 0):

The documentation in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem) says that "Return false to allow normal context menu processing to proceed, true to consume it here".

So in order to ensure the code works, I would write

```
case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE:
    return true;
```

instead of

```
case Constants.Context_Menu_Items.CONTEXT_MENU_CLOSE:
    break;
```

thus avoiding a call to super.onContextItemSelected(item)